# Unable to change format of jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to set the format of a jQuery datepicker to `dd-mm-yy`, and log it to the console when I click a button. The code I have is:

```
$('#ajaxButton').click(function () {
    var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    }).val();
    console.log(date);
});
```

> The date `09/01/2016` is being logged to the console

I can't figure out why, can anyone help?

Comment: can you share the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will give you date in your given format :

```js
$('#ajaxButton').click(function () {
  console.log(date.val());
});
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="button" id="ajaxButton" value="click"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Patel